# How to change style of symbol in layer ? Categorized type Pyqgis

Tags: styles

i would like to know how to change style (opacity, color etc) of shape in Pyqgis 
For ex. I have got 1 poligon layer, in this layer 2 shapes. 
I want to change style one of them, using categorized ( first shape Has got value '1' next '2', name of attribute - 'NO'

Comment: Please, add sample code

Comment: There is no sample code im using qgis to this and i want it to work from python console